# Compare two lists and produce a list of names not duplicated

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-filter

I have one list of total available people and the second list of people who have been assigned. I would like to auto-populate a third list of the people (from the first list) who have not been assigned (list B). Basically whichever names from column A that are not used in Column B would show up in Column C.

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+
|    | A        | B        | C        |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  |   All    | Assigned |   Free   |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 2  | AJ       | AJ       | Dayna    |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 3  | Dayna    | Leah     | Kristina |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 4  | Kristina | Mag      | Mai      |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 5  | Leah     | Milla    | Sarah    |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 6  | Mag      | Mimi     |          |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 7  | Mai      | Oksana   |          |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 8  | Milla    | Richelle |          |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 9  | Mimi     |          |          |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 10 | Oksana   |          |          |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 11 | Richelle |          |          |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 12 | Sarah    |          |          |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C2: `=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(A2:B; ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A; B2:B; 0))))`**

---

**bonus knowledge:**

- to achieve the opposite:
  **`=FILTER(A2:A; REGEXMATCH(A2:A; "^"&JOIN("|"; FILTER(B2:B; LEN(B2:B)))&"$"))`**
- to avoid **`#REF!`** error if **D** column exists:
  **`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(A2:B; ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A; B2:B; 0))); 1000; 1)`**

Comment: Awesome thank you. I think this is will be exactly what I need.